# "Карусель" для картинок

Tags: android

У меня есть 10 картинок в формате gif. 
Хочу чтобы они отображались вертикально и их можно было листать влево и вправо. При этом нужно, чтобы картинка в центре была чуть больше размером, а те которые отходят от нее влево и вправо меньше и меньше.

Примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что пробовал:

библиотеку [FancyCoverFlow](https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow)

но она используют deprecated class Gallery

Нашел замену:

[EcoGallery](https://github.com/falnatsheh/EcoGallery)

Но в ней нет такого, чтобы картинки по мере отдаления уменьешлись..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данная "карусель" называется CoverFlow. Использовал вот [это](https://github.com/moondroid/CoverFlow) решение. Все очень просто настраивается, рекомендую

Comment: спасибо, сейчас попробую и отпишу!

Comment: Большое спасибо! Прикрутил, работает вроде как надо. Чуток позже разберу конфиги этой либы.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста!