# Как расчитывать, какая из View в RecyclerView занимает более половины экрана?

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter, customview

У меня есть RecyclerView, в которой, пока, находится 3 кастомных View. RecyclerView можно скроллить по горизонтали, а ширина каждого View равна ширине экрана. Я хочу в TextView показывать, какая из View, в данный момент занимает более половины экрана, то есть, является основной в данный момент времени. Как это сделать?

MainScreenActivity.class

```
public class MainScreenActivity extends BaseActivity implements View.OnClickListener, MainScreenView {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}
```

MyAdapter.class

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private List<ChartDefiner> chartDefiners;
    private DataView dataView;

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ChartView chartView;

        public MyViewHolder(ChartView chartView) {
            super(chartView);
            this.chartView = chartView;
        }
    }

    public MyAdapter(List<ChartDefiner> chartDefiners, DataView dataView) {
        this.chartDefiners = chartDefiners;
        this.dataView = dataView;
    }

    @Override
    public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        ChartView v = (ChartView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chart_layout, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.chartView.initData();
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return chartDefiners.size();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Если ваши кастомные вью будут примерно одинаковые, то почему бы не использовать [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager)? Просто свайпайте их, и все. Это даст нужный результат

Comment: Проблема в том, что View будет меняться размер при зуме. Кроме того, Я пробовал ViewPager, но это не давало плавности в переходах

Comment: тогда вам нужно использовать что-то наподобие карусели..вот посмотрите, может поможет чем-то https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/472514/Карусель-для-картинок