# media player android view создание

Tags: android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можете подсказать из каких view компонентов состоит данное view, хотелось бы создать что то похожее... особенно голосовое...

Answer (score 0):

В целом я считаю что вопрос не корректен, так как решений достаточно много и каждый их решает по свойму. Карточи песен можно реализовать как через RecyclerView так и ViewPager или ViewPager2(смесь первух двух, но с уклоном во второе), называется это [карусель картинок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/472515/238266)(оказалось существует готовый вариант).  Кнопки это: imageView, button или вообще view (кнопки сделать их большое множество). Список в низу это RecyclerView. Всё! А теперь то что из вопроса имеет смысл audiowave - их тоже достаточно многое количество, но мне нравится вот эта библиотека: [Audiogram](https://github.com/alxrm/audiowave-progressbar). Не сложная в настройке, лёгкая и достаточно функцианальная.