# Жесты в приложении android

Tags: java, android

Как сделать так, чтобы пр свайпе снизу вверх менялась картинка (при каждом новом жесте)?  Т.е есть картинки, которые меняются с помощью seelbar, а как сделать так чтобы использовать жесты, вместо seekbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем понятно что вы хотите сделать. Но похоже у вас есть набор картинок, покладите их в список. Создайте переменную, хоторая будет хранить индекс активной картинки, при свайпе добавляйте к ней единицу, если результат больше размера вашего списка присваивайте ноль (учтите список отсчитывается от нулевого элемента) и доставайте нулевой элемент. Теперь осталось за малым, отслеживать свайпы. Можно использовать OnTouchListener, а можно  попробовать использовать ViewPager2 он умеет реализовывать вертикальную прокрутку. В такой релизации вам не нужно будет замарачиваться об этом всём, вы пишете адаптер и передаёте в него ваш список картинок. [Вот хорошая статья.](https://devcolibri.com/early-introduction-of-viewpager2/)

Comment: +1 за слово "покладите".

Comment: Как при свайпе прибавлять единицу? Я сделал так, но он не меняет картинки. Использовать ViewPager2 у меня не получилось.
int prog_scrool = 0;
if(e1.getY() - e2.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
       prog_scrool += 1; switch (prog_scrool) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                 switch (prog_scrool) {
                      case (1):
                          maps_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.maps_1);

Comment: Или как прибавлять единицу к переменной при свайпе?

Comment: @Unknown, то что вы написали в комментарии нужно добавлять в вопрос с пометкой: UPD или другой. Смотрите во ViewPager2 используется точно тот же адаптер что и в RecyclerView что упрощает с ним работу и с ним проблем быть не должно, вообще. А по вопросу жеста, у вас есть слушатель в котором вы должны выполнять проверку вами сказанного, если она истинна выполнеете ваш код (в т.ч. добавление единицы и перелистывание слайда/картинки). Я вот подумал, может быть вы хотите что-то подобное вот этому: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/472514/238266. Погуглите карусель картинок.